# Android gradle plugin - flavor dimensions by country

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I have inherited a project which has the following flavor set up in gradle build file:

```
productFlavors {
    def STRING = "String"
    def BOOLEAN = "boolean"
    def TRUE = "true"
    def FALSE = "false"
    def BASE_ENDPOINT = "BASE_ENDPOINT"

    mock {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp.mock"
        buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"mock://localhost/gt"'
    }

    qa {
        applicationId "ca.example.myapp"
        buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"https://qa-somesite.com/gt"'
    }

    qaInternal {
        applicationId ".ca.example.myapp.int"
        buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"https://internal-somesite.com/gt"'
    }

    beta {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp.beta"
        buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"https://somesite.com/gt"'
    }

    prod {
        applicationId "ca.ca.example.myapp"
        buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"https://somesite.com/gt"'
    }
}
```

nothing special going on there just flavors for production qa, mocking , etc.

This is just for for a particular country though.  Its for USA.  So these flavors are all for USA.  I need to use the same app. I'd like to create flavors for another country called France.  The france flavors have different configurations.

i was thinking i could do something like this:

```
flavorDimensions "country","buildtype"
```

to get me the flavors by country. But then how would i create my own mock,qa,qaInternal,etc flavors for the new country.

So to be clear my end goal is to have product flavors for a new country called france given the code i've pasted above all in android studio.

**UPDATE**:  Let me be more precise on what i desire and the issue.  Look at the current product flavors: mock, qa, qaInternal,beta and prod.  They all pretain to information about a USA build. This already exists in code. **The code is currently built for USA customers**.  Now i have been asked to make the code also available for **French customers** so i need a french build.

The issue is things like the applicationID, and many buildConfigField are going to be different in the french build.  How can i engineer a solution where i can have for example, a french mock, a french qa, a french qaInternal ,french beta, and a french prod just like i currently have for the USA build ?

The issue has nothing to do with locale per say, its just that we have two products a USA product and we want a french product which will have  a different configuration then USA.

take for example the mock flavor. For french i need this to happen:

```
mock {
        applicationId "french-com.example.mock"
        versionName = versionOverride + 'french-mock'
        buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"mock://localhost/french-gt"'
    }
```

Comment: Are you *really* sure that you need a new flavor just for a different country? You will wind up with hundreds, if not thousands, of build variants if you plan on supporting lots of countries. Also, why are those product flavors instead of build types?

Comment: yah i had to think about if there buildtypes or flavors but since im setting things like applicationID etc in each im going to consider it a flavor that can be produced and delivered to the business.  Im going to update my question to be more clear what i need.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing would work if you assign a `flavorDimension` to every `productFlavor`. So in your case the `build.gradle` could look like

```
flavorDimensions "country","buildtype"

productFlavors {
    def STRING = "String"
    def BOOLEAN = "boolean"
    def TRUE = "true"
    def FALSE = "false"
    def BASE_ENDPOINT = "BASE_ENDPOINT"

    mock {
        dimension 'buildtype'
        applicationId "com.example.myapp.mock"
        versionName = versionOverride + '-mock'
        buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"mock://localhost/gt"'
    }

    qa {
        dimension 'buildtype'
        applicationId "ca.example.myapp"
        versionName = versionOverride + '-qa'
        buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"https://qa-somesite.com/gt"'
    }

    qaInternal {
        dimension 'buildtype'
        applicationId ".ca.example.myapp.int"
        versionName = versionOverride + '-qaInt'
        buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"https://internal-somesite.com/gt"'
    }

    beta {
        dimension 'buildtype'
        applicationId "com.example.myapp.beta"
        versionName = versionOverride + '-beta'
        buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"https://somesite.com/gt"'
    }

    prod {
        dimension 'buildtype'
        applicationId "ca.ca.example.myapp"
        versionName = versionOverride + '-prod'
        buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"https://somesite.com/gt"'
    }

    usa {
        dimension 'country'
        // whatever else you want
    }

    france {
        dimension 'country'
        // whatever else you want
    }

}
```

With the flavorDimensions set up, you will now have a combination of productFlavors with dimension&buildtype, In this case it will be mockUsa, mockFrance, qaUsa, qaFrance etc..

Given the fact that there are *actual* buildtypes `debug` and `release`, you might end up with a huge list of variants!

Comment: im looking to set configurations by country. i updated what im looking for to be more clear. i don't think this is it.

Comment: In solution that I suggested, you will get variants like mockUsa, mockFrance, qaUsa, qaFrance.. And for country specific configurations, you can use the country block 
ex: 
`france {
    dimension 'country'
    applicationId 'something'
   // etc.
}`

Or am I missing something?

Comment: The issue is France has different beta,prod and qa settings. Your way. How do I get France to have its own set of build settings for those?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create multiple `buildType`s instead of flavors.
if you have build types France and USA, and flavors mock, qa and ... , then you would have these build variants : qaUSA , qaFrance, mockUSA, mockFrance and etc.

here is `build.gradle` example :

```
productFlavors {
        mock {
             ...
        }
        qa {
            ...
        }
    }

buildTypes {
        USA {
            ...
        }

        France {
            ...
        }
    }
```